# MariaDB table got non-consecutive primary key after running a Django application

Tags: python, django, database, mariadb

We have been running a Django application for years, and the operation accumulated multiple thousands of historical transactions.

We recently sampled through the real data and realized that the `transaction` table contains non-consecutive values in its primary key `id` column.

The jumping primary keys widely exist in the data, and typically, a sample query for `id` with an interval of 1000 will only yield three hundred records.

By reviewing the application's source code, we have the following details, not sure if relevant, though.

- The DDL has `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `id` column, so we believe the database will automatically increment on this column.
- In the Python source code, the model `Transaction` does not contain the primary key `id` column, so this column is added by the Django framework.
- In the function writing the transaction to database, there is no mention of the primary key `id` column either. However, the function has `@transaction.atomic`, and we are not sure whether the notation has any influence on the system behavior.
- The technical stack is: `MariaDB v10.5`, `Python v3.7`, `Django v3.1.4`.

**Our Question:**

- Why does the database have non-consecutive primary keys on the table?
- Is it common for applications to have non-consecutive primary keys in the database?

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**The DDL of the `transaction` table generated by Django's data migration:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `app_transaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_amount` decimal(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fulfillment_ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `create_ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `rec_del` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_price` decimal(11,4) NOT NULL,
  `shopping_card_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `has_order_item_logs` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app_transa_product_id_xxxxxxxx_fk_app_product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `app_transaction_create_ts_xxxxxxxx` (`create_ts`),
  KEY `app_transaction_update_ts_xxxxxxxx` (`update_ts`),
  KEY `app_transaction_fulfillment_ts_xxxxxxxx` (`fulfillment_ts`),
  CONSTRAINT `app_transact_product_id_xxxxxxxx_fk_a` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `app_product` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=xxxxxx DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Have you ever deleted rows from this table?